# Spark-submit cluster mode - NoClassDefFoundError

Tags: apache-spark, spark-submit

i am getting below error while submitting spark job in cluster mode.
–deploy-mode client model is working fine

```
/usr/spark2.0.2/bin/    spark-submit --name hello --master yarn --deploy-mode client --executor-memory 1g --executor-cores 1 --num-executors 1 --class com.first.load.Hello /home/udaychitukula6587/first.load/target/scala-2.10/helloworld_2.10-1.0.jar
```

**Below one throwing error:**

```
/usr/spark2.0.2/bin/    spark-submit --name hello --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster --executor-memory 1g --executor-cores 1 --num-executors 1 --class com.first.load.Hello /home/udaychitukula6587/first.load/target/scala-2.10/helloworld_2.10-1.0.jar*
```

**ERROR:**

```
*:: problems summary ::
:::: ERRORS
_ unknown resolver null_
:: USE VERBOSE OR DEBUG MESSAGE LEVEL FOR MORE DETAILS
:: retrieving :: org.apache.spark#spark-submit-parent
_ confs: [default]_
_ 0 artifacts copied, 17 already retrieved (0kB/19ms)_

    Exception in thread “main” java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/jersey/api/client/config/ClientConfig
    _ at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.api.TimelineClient.createTimelineClient(TimelineClient.java:55)_
    _ at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.api.impl.YarnClientImpl.createTimelineClient(YarnClientImpl.java:181)_
    _ at org.apache.hadoop.yarn.client.api.impl.YarnClientImpl.serviceInit(YarnClientImpl.java:168)_*
```

this program is to print welcome message

please help me in resolving this

Comment: What version of Hadoop are you using? How are you building the JAR?

Answer (score 0):

It seems you're missing the jersey-client in your classpath. Download and add it to your classpath using `--jars` option